# Open document by dropping it on document-based application icon in OS X

Tags: cocoa

I'm making a document-based application where documents are application bundles.
I can open them through "File → Open" menu fine. But when I try to drop them on the Dock icon they get rejected and the icon doesn't highlight.

I've searched this issue and it seems like it should just work given that LSItemContentTypes property is specified. Here is my Info.plist excerpt:

```
CFBundleDocumentTypes = (
    {   CFBundleTypeName = "Example";
        CFBundleTypeRole = "Editor";
        LSHandlerRank = "Alternate";
        LSItemContentTypes = ( "com.apple.application-bundle" );
        NSDocumentClass = "Example";
        NSExportableTypes = ( "com.apple.application-bundle" );
    },
);
```

(I am developing outside of Xcode, this is a TextMate-formatted plist file.)

Also I tried implementing `application:openFile:` and `application:openFiles:` on my app delegate but they never get called.

There are no warnings or other related messages in the log. What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe add the extension?
`<key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key><array><string>app</string></array>`

Comment: Doesn't work. I don't have it because LSItemContentTypes takes precedence over it. See  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to set `LSTypeIsPackage` to `YES`.

That's the only difference I see with your plist stuff and mine that opens packages.

After that, maybe you need to logout/login, restart the app, or whatever to "refresh the system/launch services"?

Comment: I've rebooted my Mac, it doesn't help. According to the documentation: "this key is ignored if the LSItemContentTypes key is present" https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html

Comment: Anyway, I'm glad to know that my plist is fine. I will try to reproduce the problem on a new app, maybe there is something wrong in my app in particular.